# Using spaghetti squash for 'pasta'

Tags: substitutions, low-carb, squash, spaghetti

I've recently gotten into making primal/paleo cooking, i.e. (no grains,legumes,processed foods) and have been meaning to try spaghetti w/meat sauce with spaghetti squash noodles instead of regular pasta. Is there a particular method of cooking the squash that helps form better noodles than others? Any other methods to help the 'pasta' come out more pasta-like?

Comment: May I ask why?  There's a reason primitive man died at 25.

Comment: @chris: I doubt that diet was that reason; among other factors, I'd consider the [lack of] sanitation or medical care to be some of the primary determinants of typical lifespan.

Comment: That said, I don't think we need two additional tags for a specific named diet.  The "paleo" diet is basically a low-carb diet and I think that will suffice.

Comment: Paleo is not just low carb, it's also a pro-organic and anti-processed food diet.

Comment: @chris Paleolithic humans had a life expectancy of 33 years at birth; life expectancy went up to 54 years if they made it to age 15. Neolithic man had a life expectancy of 20 years (this was after the agricultural revolution when diets changed). Current life expectancy is 67 years.

Comment: @Aaronut Paleolithic or (Paleo) should be a tag, and terming it as a "low-carb diet" is a broad simplification.  To quote Wikipedia on the make-up of the diet; "Meat, fish, vegetables, fruit, roots, and nuts make up most of the modern Paleolithic diet. It does not include grains, legumes, dairy products, salt, refined sugar, and processed oils." https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleolithic_diet

Comment: @wonea: I'll grant you that was a poor choice of synonym, however, and considering that I *follow* it, I feel pretty comfortable labeling it as simply low-glycemic. The entire *scientific* basis of paleo - excluding the parts constituting faddish elitism and amateurish articles written on simplified wikis - is based on insulin response. I'd *much* rather use that as a tag than "paleo" since low-glycemic foods are common in many other diets (most notably/popularly the South Beach diet).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split the squash in half lengthwise, drizzle with olive oil, and place face-down on a foil-covered baking sheet. I usually roast for 45 min to an hour, depending on the size of the squash. The inside 'noodles' can then be scooped out with a fork for an awesome pasta substitution. Enjoy!

Comment: Yep, that's generally how I've done this as well. I don't really think of it as a pasta replacement though, just some stringy stuff that tastes pretty good. Like all winter squash, it enjoys brown butter as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can also make it in the microwave. Either split first, remove the seeds and stringy goop, and place face-down on a microwave-safe plate or just prick it with a fork and cook it. Time will depend on size, but cook it until it's nice and soft. Then just use a fork to scrape out the flesh. The flesh will automatically come out in strings.

You can also bake it whole -- which means that you'll have to scrape out the seeds after it's cooked. Again, make sure to prick it so that it doesn't split on its own.

One warning, though -- it will have a crispier texture than noodles. No matter how long you cook it, it still won't be as soft as pasta. But that texture is actually one of the attractions, for me. It's got a bit of a crunch, which is nice.

Comment: This is what I do, microwave 1/2 a squash for 10 minutes. The taste and texture really is halfway between spagetti and squash.